# SQL Server return Select statement with XML datatype and convert it into DataSet in C#, ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml, sqlconnection

In my database table, I have a column name 'SectionDatatable' which are in XML datatype. In my C# code, after I have connection to database to my database and I make a query to get SectionDatatablewhich is XML format in my database, UserDefinedSectionData. I need to convert the 'SectionDatatable' in XML Datatype and convert it into DataSet, how can I do it. I have stuck for 1 day, the following is my code.

```
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        csb.DataSource = @"CPX-XSYPQKSA91D\SQLEXPRESS";
        csb.InitialCatalog = "DNN_Database";
        csb.IntegratedSecurity = true;

        string connString = csb.ToString();

        string queryString = "select * FROM UserDefinedSectionData WHERE SectionDataTabId = @tabId";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = queryString;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("tabId", tabId));
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string sectionData= reader["SectionDatatable"].ToString();
                    int moduleId = Int32.Parse(reader["SectionDataModuleId"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why you used UserDefinedSectionData as table though you mentioned it is a column? What is table name and column name?

Comment: @GaurangDave So sorry, I have correct it already. SectionDatatable is the column from UserDefinedSectionData Table

Comment: Check my answer below. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simple example of converting `XML` string to `DataSet`. This sample also demonstrates processing all tables in `DataSet`.

You need to replace XML string in this sample with your XML output from database. You can change code as per you need to access data.

```
string RESULT_OF_SectionDatatable = "<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>";
var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(RESULT_OF_SectionDatatable));

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(xmlReader);

foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
    Console.WriteLine(table);
    Console.WriteLine();

    foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(table.Columns[i].ColumnName +"\t" + row[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```