# Parse SQL XML data type and remove empty nodes

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I have a table with 2 columns. ID in int  data type and XML_Data in XML data type. This XML_Data column has all the data needed for my XML from start tag to end tag. I need to write a c# program to read this XML column by calling using an Stored procedure and then remove if any empty nodes are present .Then I need to rename the XML file with id and current date time and save it in a file system. I know the steps to remove empty nodes and rename but unsure on how to parse the column with sql XML data type using C#. please help

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "parse the column with sql XML data type?"

If you mean get the sql query result into an xml data type in c# use this SO:

[SQL Server return Select statement with XML datatype and convert it into DataSet in C#, ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808453/sql-server-return-select-statement-with-xml-datatype-and-convert-it-into-dataset)

If you are trying to do things within sql with the xml data type column check out this Red Gate article:

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/the-xml-methods-in-sql-server/

Hope these help.  I would need a more specific question to come up with a more specific answer at this point.